# Why doesn't Captain Mal let Saffron answer at the end of "Our Mrs. Reynolds"?

Tags: firefly

At the end of episode "[Our Mrs Reynolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Mrs._Reynolds)" Captain Mal confronts Saffron for answers, ending with asking what her real name is.

To me it appears that she hesitates and he knocks her out. I can get why he wouldn't believe anything she might say, but I would have thought he'd listen to her lies. It would seem any information she might give could be a source to slip up.

Why doesn't he let her answer?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [shooting script](http://www.myths.com/pub/tv/firefly/script-our-mrs-reynolds.html) makes it pretty clear that the pause is sufficient warning to him that she's preparing to tell another lie. He'd rather just not listen to it.

> **MAL** : *I got one question for you. Just one  thing I'd like to know straight up.*
>
> **SAFFRON** : *Ask me.*
>
> **MAL** : *What's your real name?*
>
> She looks at him... **looks away, considering the question...**
>   -- and he slams the butt of his gun into her chin, knocking her out cold.
>
> He stands, regards her genuinely vulnerable form. Says with a kind of
>   sadness:
>
> **MAL** (cont'd) : **You'd only've lied anyhow.**
>
> A beat, and he leaves.

Comment: I had forgotten about that last line! Time to watch it again.